# SDN4 - Cannot findById with list of id

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j-4

In old version, SDN3, I can use findById(List id), but after upgrade to SDN4, I cannot use this function again, always return empty.

This is my sample class :

```
@NodeEntity
public class Right{

    @GraphId
    Long graphId;

    String id; //random generated UUID

    String name;

    //Properties & Constructor
}
```

And then I have RightRepository that contain these code :

```
public interface RightRepository extends GraphRepository<Right> {
    List<Right> findById(List<String> id);
}
```

Instead of use Loop to get per ID, I need to call repository only once, and get the List (without using findAll())

Is SDN4 already not support it? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Could you try annotating the method with a custom query. Example `@Query("MATCH (n:Right) WHERE n.id IN {rightIds} RETURN n")
List<Right> findRightById(@Param("rightIds") List<String> rightIds);`

Comment: Yes, its work with custom Query. But before upgrade to SDN4, I can use that method with SDN3.

Comment: I think it's the only way to accomplish it at the moment. I'll be waiting for other answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I post in a comment and after a further investigation, I think that a custom query is the only way to accomplish your requirement at the moment. This works:

```
@Query("MATCH (n:Right) WHERE n.id IN {rightIds} RETURN n") 
List<Right> findRightById(@Param("rightIds") List<String> rightIds);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: For now, I think this answer is the only way to accomplish my question. Anyway thank you @troig

Comment: While waiting for new update, no other answer except this one. hahha. Thank you