# Stale data in view after update Neo4j date-base with a collection

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Framework included in project :  Spring Boot , Spring Security, Spring Web, Neo4j, Tomcat etc

Problem to update  Neo4j database with custom query  like this ( a collection as a parameter  )

```
@Query("START user=node({u}) SET user.authorities = {rightIds} RETURN user") 

User putRolesByArray(@Param("u")User user, @Param("rightIds") List<String> rightIds);
```

In Spring   printout result of query (System.out.println) return no any changes on objects . No error in console. But here some going wrong because in Neo4j browser I can see correct  changes applied to the User object but not in Java part in runtime, if rebuild project changed object in Java is correct.  I find this third [How to pass Collection Parameters to Repository Queries for Neo4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376362/how-to-pass-collection-parameters-to-repository-queries-for-neo4j)     Changing the bolt to http driver and  version of the  bolt driver from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0. not help.
Spring Securety? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is defined and expected behaviour. Please see the reference documentation.

> Once an entity is tracked by the session, reloading this entity within the scope of the same session will result in the session cache returning the previously loaded entity.

http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:configuration

If you want to get the updated state you need to clear the Session.

```
session.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks  for remind, completely fogged about the session.